# how to overcome WCF soap feature?

Tags: wcf

in my understanding, WCF internally does some SOAP work before the serialization process.
is there a way to skip the soap feature and render source data directly to binary format?

Answer (score 1):

WCF doesn't do anything SOAP-y untill you apply a binding that implements SOAP. If you want binary, take a look at net.TCP or write your own binding.

See [Windows Communcation Foundation Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733027%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: What is in System.ServiceModel.Chanel.Message?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, my understanding WCF translate raw data to SOAP/XML then serialised in user format before giving out to client and the reserve in in client side.

Comment: in the case of output data in binary format, before it gets to binary what did WCF do to the data?

Comment: Did you read about the net.TCP or custom bindings? I don't know why the Message class mentions SOAP if that is what you're hinting at, perhaps an artifact from its initial design. You don't have to care how WCF works internally. You return a CLR object from your service, WCF puts that in a Message object and then it gets serialized by the binding of your choosing. Explain what exactly you want to do and what you have tried to do and what happened, don't go guessing about internal operations.

Comment: the problem I have here is relating to performance, in our environment, performance is everything. I currently use a custom socket client/server and it is so much faster comparing to WCF but sometime we have some hit cups. I like to move to WCF but the same amount of data would take so long to move to client side.

Comment: Enable [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to see what happens internally.